# Scikit-Learn SVC hangs on small data set

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use scikit-learn to fit a SVM to my data.  However, Python hangs on the last line below when I try to fit the data.  I let this run for 12 hours before killing it.  trainX has 100 features and 1000 rows.  It's also a dense matrix, if that makes a difference.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    trainX,trainY,testX,testY,validateX,validateY = splitData()
    mdl = svm.SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=500, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
        gamma=0.1, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False,
        shrinking=True, tol=0.1, verbose=True)
    mdl.fit(trainX,trainY)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should normalize the data using `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler` or `StandardScaler`.